# Minus vs less (in math)

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, prepositions, synonyms

We used to talk about subtractions employing the word minus *as a preposition*  like "10 minus 5 is 5... "what is 5 minus 3?" ....

Is it OK to replace the word minus by "**less**" in sentences like "5 less 3 is 2" or "how many is 10 less 5?" (which I see **a few old folks still use**)?

Moreover, I find that less *as a preposition* is also still *in use*. So, I think this usage is grammatically possible.

Comment: [Minus as a preposition is still in use](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/minus) if your concern is that it isn't.

Comment: If you find that "*less* as a preposition is still in use" why should it not be correct if *minus* is correct as a preposition? It may be falling out of favour, but it's correct for the people who still use it. Is the question clear? I must have missed something.

Comment: How about answers that include the place?  Maybe "5 less 3" is more common in Scotland, and less common in Canada?

Comment: There is an argument that operations be seen (at least partly) as transformations, with a verby bias.  With additions, 10 add 3 equals 13. The increment is distinct from the starting number.  7 times 6 is 42. 6 take 2 is 4. Some even use say 'three square is nine'.

Comment: 6 takeaway 2 is 4 and sometimes, 2 from 6 leaves 4 are also common..

Answer (score 5):

*Less* is synonymous with *minus* but is less common. It can be used in straightforward cases like "Ten less three is seven," but it tends to be used mainly in other situations, where *minus* might be less appropriate.

It is used especially where the amount subtracted is expressed by a phrase rather than a numerical value.

> *The weight so found, less the weight of the sieve, shall be considered to be the weight of the drained grapefruit.*

> *Nor was the sentence of two years less a day within the normal range for such offences.*

*Less* is used as a preposition in the sense "with the exception of."

> *The only way such error may be cured is by approval of the sentence less the bad conduct discharge, or by ordering a rehearing.*

Generally, *less* seems more likely to be found in highly formal styles.

> *The Prophet (peace be upon him) said: Allah has ninety-nine names, one hundred less one. Anyone who learns them will enter Jannah.*